# Can you get a NSDictionary key from a value

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any way of getting a key value from an NSDictionary based on its value? I can get the value based on the key in several ways but I need to get at the key.

Using the example below how would I be able to get the key if my value was QuestionType?

```
NSDictionary *question = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:  
                @"QuestionType", @"0",
                @"Answer", @"1",
                nil];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `-[NSDictionary allKeysForObject:]`. It returns an `NSArray` of keys, because there could be more than one key for any given object.

In your example:

```
NSDictionary *question = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:  
                @"QuestionType", @"0",
                @"Answer", @"1",
                nil];
for (NSString *key in [question allKeysForObject:@"QuestionType"]) {
    NSLog(@"Key: %@", key);
}
```

By the way, is there any particular reason why your keys (`@"0"` and `@"1"`) are `NSString`s? You can use any object that supports `NSCopying` as a key, so `NSNumber` might be a better choice here.

Comment: To simply use NSNumbers instead of NSStrings, just write @0 instead of @"0".